# Create UserControl dynamically (WPF)

Tags: wpf, user-controls

How can I create an instance of my UserControl dynamically (in code behind) and display it on the Canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
YourUserControlClassName myUC = new YourUserControlClassName();
myCanvas.Children.Add(myUC);
```

If myCanvas is not dynamic and is in xaml then you need this to get the reference myCanvas

```
Canvas myCanvas = (Canvas)this.FindName("CanvasNameInXaml");
```

Comment: @JooLio: Although this solves your problem, this is a bad approach. If you portray the scenario better, I would try to suggest a better design.

Comment: Canvas has Name attribute. I can use it in my code by name. But I didn't know I can get control by it's String name o_O. That may be very usefull.